# Lemma 2.8 - Elements of integration by Bartle

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

I'm self studying Measure Theory by Bartle's book and I have a doubt in the proof of a lemma. Before I say what is the lemma and what is my doubt, I would like to say that the book is available [here](http://fejer.ucol.mx/andres/Proba/Bartle%20Elements%20of%20Integration.pdf) if anyone wants to see and I would like to introduce some notation according to the Bartle's book that I believe it's necessary to understand the proof of the lemma.

$\textbf{Notation:}$

(i) $\overline{\mathbb{R}} := \mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \} $ is the extended real number system and the function with codomain $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are said to be extended real valued functions.

(ii) $\textbf{X}$ in bold is the $\sigma-$algebra of a set $X$.

(iii) The collection of all extended real valued $\textbf{X}-$measurable function on $X$ is denoted by $M(X, \textbf{X})$.

> $\textbf{Lemma 2.8}$ An extended real valued function $f$ is measurable if and only if the sets
>
> $$A := \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) = +\infty \} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.5cm} B := \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) = - \infty \}$$ belong to $\textbf{X}$ and the real-valued function $f_1$ defined by
>
> $$f_1(x) := f(x), x \notin A \cup B$$
>
> $$f_1(x) := 0, x \in A \cup B$$
>
> is measurable.
>
> $\textbf{Proof:}$
>
> If $f \in M(X, \textbf{X})$, it has already been noted that $A$ and $B$ belong to $\textbf{X}$. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \geq 0$, then
>
> $$\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) > \alpha \} = \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \} \ \backslash \ A$$
>
> If $\alpha < 0$, then
>
> $$\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) > \alpha \} = \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \} \cup B$$

The proof continues, but my doubt emerges here. I would like to know why $\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) > \alpha \} = \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \} \cup B$? I don't know why $\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) > \alpha \}$ have points of $B$ since $\alpha$ is fixed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equality is valid for $\alpha <0$, so
\begin{align}\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) > \alpha \}&=\{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \}\cup\{ x \in X \ ; \ f_1(x) =0 \}\\[1ex]
&=\{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \}\cup (A\cup B)\\[1ex]
&=\{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \}\cup B
\end{align}
since   $\;A\subset \{ x \in X \ ; \ f(x) > \alpha \}$.

Comment: I understood now, thanks a lot!

Comment: I was struggling here too. Thanks!